# Click textfiled to display data from mysql

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have a web based system where there are two fields. one is client name and the other is client description. When the user selects the client name from the drop down options the client description should automatically display the description from the database as in the database its has already been created a description for every client. Below is code :
{

```
if($client=="" || $description=="" || $guard=="" || $category=="" || $location=="" || $date=="")
{$err="<font color='red'>All fields required</font>";   
}else{
$sql="INSERT INTO schedule(client_name, description_, guard, category, _location,date) VALUES('$client','$description','$guard','$category','$location',  NOW()) ";         
        if ( ! mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));
    }}      
    $err="<font color='green'>Schedule added Successfully</font>";  
}?><h2>Add New Schedule</h2>`<form method="post">`

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><?php echo @$err;?></div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="inputState">Client Name</label>
  <select id="inputState"  name="client" class="form-control" required>
 <option selected>Choose..</option>
    <?php 
      $sql= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT client_name FROM contract");
      while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo "<option value='".$res['client_name']."'>".$res['client_name']."</option>";
      }?>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="inputType">Contrat Description</label>
<input type="text" name="description" id="" class="form-control">`$q=mysqli_query($conn,"select description_ from contract where client_name='".$_GET['client_name']."'");
$res=mysqli_fetch_array($q);` <input type="text" name="client" id="" value="<?php echo $res['description_'];?>" class="form-control" > </div>`
```

Comment: So when the user selects the client name on the description it does not display anything

Comment: PHP is a server-side scripting language, you can't perform dynamic content loading using PHP.
 You need to combine Javascript for this.

Comment: How can you assist me on this plz

Comment: You better have a look at this tutorial
 https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_php.asp

Comment: Appears to be the same question asked here by a different account, https://stackoverflow.com/q/74477830/1427878

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-side and cannot change objects in the DOM. From your code above, I assume you are not submitting the form. The changes you are looking for need to happen on the front end in the DOM, so you either need to submit the form with a javaScript (on select) or use ajax.

Here is a sample: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

Comment: i added the below code right after php code on the client field:

Comment: <div id="txtHint">Customer info will be listed here...</div>

<script>
function showCustomer(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "get description_ from contract.php?q="+str);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
      </select>
    </div>